# What does the number mean in this statement: DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '2020-01-03');

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

The documentation states

```
DATEDIFF(interval, date1, date2);
```

I can't find any info on what a number means there.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DATEDIFF is not ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Syntax suggests `SQL Server` DB.

Comment: It means the person who wrote this code took some very tricky shortcuts. I'm sure you will find more of this unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

That would mean that the date is "6".  If you run:

```
select convert(datetime,  6)
```

You will get a value.

More commonly, I think, it means that the write of the code intended `DATEADD()` rather than `DATEDIFF()`.

Answer (score 0):

That statement says, the week difference :

```
DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '2020-01-03')
```

`6` would be `1900-01-07`

So, you will get week difference for `'1900-01-07' & '2020-01-03'`

When you pass numeric value it will considered as no of days (being added in default date `1900-01-01`)

For example, if you have a numeric value `1`

```
select convert(datetime, 1)
```

You will get `1900-01-02 00:00:00.000`, considering default date `1900-01-01`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the code

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(WK, 6 , '20200103')
```

Is actually starting from this date:

> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'

The 6 is then adding 6 days to that date, making it the 7th of jan.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(WK, '19000107', '20200103')
```

Running those 2 selects would output the same.

Answer (score 0):

The legacy `datetime` datatype is stored as two 32 bit integers concatenated together.

One integer is the offset in days from the base date of 1st Jan 1900, the other integer is the number of ticks for the time component.

Similarly SQL Server has long allowed casts between numeric types and datetime that correspond with this scheme. The integer `0` casts to Monday 1900-01-01, and `6` to Sunday 1900-01-07 for example.

When you call `DATEDIFF` and pass an integer as either of the last 2 parameters it gets implicitly cast to `DATETIME` so is the same as `DATEDIFF(wk, {d '1900-01-07'}, date_under_test}`.

Whilst the output of that expression is likely not interesting on its own it might be used to group values belonging to the same week (starting Sunday) together or combined with `DATEADD` to add this number of weeks plus one back on to the anchor date to get the following Sunday to `date_under_test`  or similar.